# Is there a simple way to get the colour of a pixel?

Tags: image-processing, color

[`PixelValue`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PixelValue.html) will extract the channel values at a certain pixel. It returns a vector of numbers, not a colour. Is there a *simple* way to extract the colour of a pixel as an expression that is [`ColorQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorQ.html)? The image could have an arbitrary colour space.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps something like this:

```
ColorConvert[
 PixelValue[im, pos],
 OptionValue[Options[im], ColorSpace] -> ImageColorSpace[im]
]
```

where `im` is an image and `pos` is a pixel position, e.g., `{100, 150}`.

The basic idea is to use `ColorConvert` to automatically get the correct head for the image's colour space (e.g. `RGBColor` or `CMYKColor`). For this, we need the syntax `ColorConvert[list, colspace1 -> colspace2]` where `colspace1` should define the interpretation of the values in the list.

Comment: Could you explain the second argument? To me the left-hand side of the arrow seems like it should return the same as the right-hand side. What is the difference?

Comment: @C.E. Sorry, I should have been more verbose (I'm trying to get something working in parallel to asking...) What I am still confused about is the impact of the `ColorSpace` being a `ColorProfileData` object. I was trying to deal with this. For example, take the first example from the `ColorProfileData` doc page. The version I showed here effectively does `ColorConvert[{a,b,c,d}, ColorProfileData[...] -> "CMYK"]`. I *think* this is the correct interpretation of the colour. We cannot have a `ColorProfileData` in a colour object (like `CMYKColor` ), so on the RHS I just used `"CMYK"`.

Comment: Any feedback about the use of `ColorProfileData` is welcome ...

Comment: @C.E. I am thoroughly confused. New question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/221271/12